# Is it possible to install Linux Mint on a PC that already has Windows 10 with two disk partitions?

Tags: linux, dual-boot, grub

On my PC, which is an Asus rog strix v553, I have Windows 10 installed with two disk partitions.

I have downloaded Linux Mint 18.3 and made a bootable USB drive, but when I try to boot from it and start the Linux mint installation, an error is shown on the screen saying

> [0] receiver error (first)

then the Linux Mint Icon appears and the PC gets blocked. I waited for 30 minutes thinking that it is normal, but nothing changed, so I tried to search for a solution.

All of the tutorials that I've watched had it installed on a new Windows with only one disk partition (no data, fearing that that data will be lost after Linux installation).

I want to take a few GBs from one of my partitions and install Linux Mint on it, without deleting any of my previous data already installed on Windows. Is that possible?

Comment: Does Linux Mint boot up at all from the USB?

Comment: No! When I choose start linux mint , the error message shows for half a second then the Linux mint icon appears and stays like that

Comment: Did you verify the downloaded iso and verify the usb?

Comment: That error message suggests there's something wrong with the media or the bus. Chances are the USB bus is fine. I'd try a different usb drive.

Comment: @jdwolf , the iso is dowloaded from the official site , so i think it is fine , yet I want to know how to verify it along with the USB

Comment: https://linuxmint.com/verify.php

Comment: I couldn't get the files , It opens a new tab in chrome showing the content of that file , so I created a file in my home/iso directory and pasted that content but the process didn't work

Comment: Well , I installed successfuly an older version of linux mint which is 17.3 , yet I'm having a trouble with my touchpad and my sound driver . And still getting the [0] receiver error but this time it went through the install process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem , caused by the graphic card , i just added nouveau.modeset=0 to the end of the linux line in the grub

Answer (score 0):

That error has nothing to do with having partitions - the disk isn't even booting.

Once your installer disk boots, then Yes, no problem.  Only requirements are to have enough free space on one of the Windows partitions to resize it and create the space for Linux, and to not have used all 4 primary partitions (so you can make an extended and then logical partitions).

Depending on what you want Linux for, you could be better off using a virtualized instance in VirtualBox....

Comment: Yes , I recognize now that partitions won't be a problem , it's just I need to install linux as an OS not on VM